# Combining 2 sql queries in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I have two tables. `voting_ip` and `country`. I want to retrieve results from `country` table where `open_id_fk` (*foreign key*) of `voting_ip` table is equal to `open_id`(*Primary Key*) of `country` table. How to write sql query to combine these queries and return the result. I am using the below code in my codeigniter model to retrieve number of occurances of `open_id_fk` in `voting_ip` table.

```
public function mostvotedans()
{
    $this->db->select('open_id_fk, COUNT(*) as total');
    $this->db->group_by('open_id_fk'); 
    $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
    $query = $this->db->get('voting_ip', 5);
    return $query;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM country WHERE open_id_fk=open_id;");  
    return $query;         
}
```

Comment: use  joins [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4916498/multiple-joins-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change it as following.

```
  public function mostvotedans()
{
  $this->db->select('c.open_id,COUNT(ip.open_id_fk) as total')->from('voting_ip ip');
  $this->db->join('country c','c.open_id=ip.open_id_fk');
  $this->db->group_by('ip.open_id_fk'); 
  $this->db->order_by('total', 'desc'); 
  $this->db->limit(5);
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query;


}
```

Comment: thank you.. this worked :) awesome.. i just modified it to get all the columns as..  $this->db->select('c.*,COUNT(ip.open_id_fk) as total')->from('voting_ip ip');

Answer (score 1):

Use a join statement :

```
$query = $this->db->select('v.open_id_fk, COUNT(v.*) AS total, c.country_name')
            ->join('country AS c', 'c.open_id = v.open_id_fk')
            ->from('voting_ip AS v')
            ->group_by('v.open_id_fk')
            ->order_by('total', 'DESC')
            ->limit(5);
```

Should work, I put 'country_name' because I don't know your tables.